# How can I "cut" my layout to put images in it?

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to "cut" my layout so I can put images in it as shown here:

[three by three grid http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5466/zonning.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5466/zonning.png)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).